# "Initialize interactive with project" in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I was using intensively the "Initialize interactive with project" option for building and initializing projects on the C# Interactive console in VS2015.

I see that in VS2017 RC this option is missing from the project context menu (right-click) of projects in the solution explorer.

Doe's anyone know a workaround for this issue?

The "Execute in Interactive" is not suitable for me, I want to have context to the full project in the interactive console.

Comment: I can see this option on right click the project on Solution Explorer. I use Final Release VS 2017 community edition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This option is available in Visual Studio 2017, in the same way it was on Visual Studio 2015 update 2. Although, it is only available on .NET Framework projects. If your project targets .NETCoreApp it will not be available.

Note: Tested on Visual Studio 2017 up to date.

Comment: This still seems to be case (after updates), and the button is similarly still missing for .NET Standard projects; however, it seems you can manually enter `#r Path\To\Dll.dll` to load a .NET Standard library. Similarly, if you have a .NET Framework project referencing a .NET Standard library, it will happily `#r` that also when you initialise with the .NET Framework project.

Comment: Same for .NET Core as well as .NET Standard; it can be loaded manually.